# Django Invalid Block Tag: 'endfor', expected 'endblock'

Tags: python, django, django-templates, render, syntax-error

What could be the cause of the this `TemplateSyntaxError` in Django?

```
Invalid block tag: 'endfor', expected 'endblock'
```

My template is pretty simple so far:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div id='beerslist'>
        {$ for beer in beers %}
        {{ beer }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

After looking at the traceback list, the 'beer' variable exists and is returning an array. How can I fix this syntax error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
{$ for beer in beers %}
```

You typed a `$` instead of `%`. That's why it doesn't recognize the `for` and complains that there's no `for` block for it to close when it sees the `endfor`.